# WPBakery Administrator disappeared from Role Manager

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, visual-composer

All of a sudden I've found that in WPBakery settings > Role Manager, Administrator role has disappeared (!?)...

[image: Role Manager]

How can I re-enable Administrator in the Role Manager??? Tried also to delete and manually reinstall plugin v6.7.0 but it didn't bring back the Administator configuration tab :(

Comment: Did you get the plugin with the theme? Did you try to disable other plugins? You may have the compatibility issue.

Comment: You were right about the most obvious things to check first: it was an old plugin version of WP Media Folder in conflict with WPBakery 6.6.0+ and WP5.8+... Lucky it was easy this time ;)

Comment: Glad you've figured it out. Good luck)